# How would I make a reset button for the jquery animation?

Tags: jquery, animation, reset

I made this jquery animation. Everything seems to be working fine with it. But I am trying to figure out how I would make a reset button for this animation so it brings it back to its starting state.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script> 

$(document).ready(function(){ 
$("button").click(function(){ 
var div = $("div"); 
div.animate({left: '100px'}, "slow"); 
div.animate({fontSize: '3em'}, "slow"); 
}); 
}); 
</script> 
</head> 
<body> 

<button>Animate!</button> 
<div  style="background:#33CCFF;height:100px;width;200px;position:absolute;">HELLO     WORLD!</div>
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try this?

html

```
<button id='animate'>Animate!</button> 
<div  class='initialStyle'>HELLO     WORLD!</div>
<button id='reset'>Reset</button>
```

css

```
.initialStyle{
    background:#33CCFF;
    height:100px;
    width;200px;
    position:absolute;
}
```

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#animate").click(function() {
        var div = $("div");
        div.animate({
            left: '100px'
        }, "slow");
        div.animate({
            fontSize: '3em'
        }, "slow");
    });

    $("#reset").click(function() {
        $('.initialStyle').removeAttr('style');
    });

});
```